# Result of .then is undefined after .then

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am loading a .json file, saving it into an array and edit my array a little bit. Unfortunately I'm new in angular and I don't know how to handle async requests (only developed in php and clientside js before) in Ionic4(Angular 7.2.2).

The loading of my json file works as expected. But if I want to edit the file via a loop my promise get resolved before the loop finished I think. This is my code. Comments showing the output. What am I doing wrong? Could you recommend something to learn async/sync requests in angular better?

```js
public getCategories()
    {
        let arrCategories;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
            this.getCategoriesData().subscribe(arrResult =>
                {
                    console.log('Ln 32');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(arrResult)); // Expected array
                    this.setAbkuerzungenDEAndBild(arrResult).then(arrKategorien =>
                        {
                            console.log('Ln 35');
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(arrKategorien)); // Output: []
                            resolve(arrKategorien);
                        },
                        error =>
                        {
                            reject('Failed loading Categories. [1]');
                        }
                    );
                },
                error =>
                {
                    reject('Failed loading Categories. [2]');
                }
            );
        });
    }


    private getCategoriesData() //Working as expected
    {
        const strUrl = 'assets/data/Kategorien.json';
        return this.objHttp.get(strUrl).pipe(
            map((res: Response) => res),
            catchError(CategoriesService.handleError)
        );
    }

    private setAbkuerzungenDEAndBild(arrCategories) //Returning [] after .then and  later on the array as expected
    {
        let arrNewCategories = [];
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
            this.objStorage.get('objSprache').then(async objSprache =>
            {
                await arrCategories.forEach((objKategorie, intIndex) =>
                {
                    if (objKategorie.intFKSpracheID === objSprache.intSpracheID) //Wenn Sprache == ausgewählt
                    {
                        //set something
                        if (objKategorie.intFKSpracheID !== '1') //Sprache nicht de
                        {
                            for (let objKategorieDE of arrCategories)
                            {
                               //Set something
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            resolve(arrNewCategories);
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm.. Just curious, since you are using Angular and RxJS, why not handle it as an observable? Why convert it to a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the mistake myself by using the following workaround:
I replaced my resolve() with

```
 if(intIndex == arrCategories.length-1)
 {
    resolve(arrNewCategories);
 }
```